# Leaflet js, width of popup does not increase when using maxWidth

Tags: leaflet

Using the below L.popup code, I would have thought the popup would expand width to match the provided image.  Seems the width of the popup is still 51 instead of 100 or 300.  Why doesnt the popup change the width?

```
var waterway = L.icon({
iconUrl: '/user_public/ski/images/waterway-canal-icon.png',
iconSize:     [32, 37], 
iconAnchor:   [16, 37], 
popupAnchor:  [0, -30] 
iconAnchor
});

var popup = L.popup({
    maxWidth: '400'
})
.setLatLng( [34.653791786519115, 138.80018854141235] )
.setContent('<img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/100/150" />')
.openOn(map);

L.marker([34.653791786519115, 138.80018854141235], 
{icon:waterway}).addTo(map).bindPopup(popup);
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue and managed to make it work by changing my CSS code as follows:

```
/* Leaflet css */

.leaflet-popup-content-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.leaflet-popup-content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: auto !important; /* Set width to auto */
  max-width: 100%; /* Ensure the content does not exceed the available width */
}

.leaflet-popup-content img {
  max-width: 40vw;
  max-height: 30vw;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}
```